# Command line argument to string in C

Tags: c

Is there a way in C to store the whole command line options and arguments in a single string. I mean if my command line is `./a.out -n 67 89 78 -i 9` then a string `str` should be able to print the whole command line. Now, what I am able to do is to print values in different vector forms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 int opt;

for(i=0;i<argc;i++){
printf("whole argv was %s\n", argv[i]);
}

while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:i")) != -1) {
switch (opt){
    case 'n':
             printf("i was %s\n", optarg);
             break;

    case 'i':
             printf("i was %s\n", optarg);
             break;
      }
   }
  return 0;
 }
```

I want this, as `optarg` only is printing my first argument and I want all the arguments to be printed, so I want to parse it after storing it in string.

Comment: Not in general, no, since it's hard to reverse-engineed whatever the shell (which is usually what invokes your program) got from the user. For instance `./a.out foo` vs `./a.out "foo"`; your program can't know if the user quoted an argument.

Comment: Since you're on Linux, you can read /proc/self/cmdline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply write a function like this:

```
char * combineargv(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    int totalsize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
       totalsize += strlen(argv[i]);
    }
    // Provides space for ' ' after each argument and a '\0' terminator.
    char *ret = malloc(totalsize + argc + 1);
    if (NULL == ret)
    {
        // Memory allocation error.
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        strcat(ret, argv[i]);
        strcat(ret, " ");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This will simply combine all of them, placing spaces between args

*Update:* I have modified the original to eliminate the buffer overflow issue.

Comment: why `totalsize + 15`?

Comment: I gave it a small buffer zone, since we are adding spaces.

Comment: and take look at the comments to bkausbk's answer. Reconcatanation of arguments is not trivial, if it shall be correct under all circumstances.

Comment: @phyrrus9 it is showing error `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer` in the line `char * ret = malloc[totalsize + 15];`

Comment: because you are still using the [], malloc() is a function. I am editing the original answer to reflect the malloc

Comment: @phyrrus9 It worked, I accepted your answer and voted it. Cheers!

Comment: shouldnt it be `malloc (totalsize + argc)` or thereabouts ?

Comment: I can make this overflow.  As I said in another comment, use `strncat`.  To make this overflow, simply provide 20 arguments on the command line.

Comment: Yes, using +argc is a better route.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has a **HUGE** potential bug. You call `strcat` passing the buffer you just got back from `malloc`. A buffer which may contain *GARBAGE*. Since `strcat` will look for the first `'\0'` (which may not be there in your buffer) your function could end up overwriting random memory. Please either `memset` the entire allocated buffer so it's full of null bytes or manually set `ret[0] = 0;` before you loop, copying arguments. @user227666 please be very careful if you do use this function.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to loop over argv and build a string with `strcat`

```
char* CommandLine = 0;
unsigned int CommandLineLength = 0;
unsigned int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    CommandLineLength += strlen(argv[i]) + 3; // Add one extra space and 2 quotes
}

CommandLine = (char*) malloc(CommandLineLength + 1);
*CommandLine = '\0';

// Todo: Check if allocation was successfull...

for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    int HasSpace = strchr(argv[i], ' ') != NULL;
    if (HasSpace) {
        strcat(CommandLine, "\"");
    }
    strcat(CommandLine, argv[i]);
    if (HasSpace) {
        strcat(CommandLine, "\"");
    }
    strcat(CommandLine, " ");
}
// Do something with CommandLine ...
free(CommandLine);
```

Comment: you should add at least one blank between two arguments

Comment: Of course, one space charcter should be included. If one command line argument itself contains spaces, the command line should be quoted with "".

Comment: don't want to annoy you, but now `CommandLineLength += strlen(argv[i]);` should be changed to `... + 3;`  --- one for the blank and two for the quotation (or you check twice) :-)

Comment: @bkausbk your code gave me the following errors: `In function ‘main’:
fun27.c:21:15: error: ‘new’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fun27.c:21:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
fun27.c:21:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘char’
fun27.c:25:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
`

Comment: Use `strncat` instead of `strcat`.  `strcat` is usually poisoned by source control rules or makefiles, because it has potential to introduce buffer overflow vulnerabilities.  `strncat` takes a size argument, allowing you to ensure that the buffer doesn't overflow.

Comment: and just to be beastly: what about arguments that contain at least one space plus the character '"' itself?

Comment: @Craig using `strncat` shows error as ` too few arguments to function ‘strncat’
`

Comment: @user227666 both answers are C++ not C. But you can reloace `new char...` by `malloc( CommandLineLength + 1 )` and `delete ...` by `free( CommandLine )`

Comment: The tag for this question is `C`.  But someone is writing a `C` implementation of a `C++` program...?  Ditch the `new` operator and have a look at `malloc` man page, or alternatively, look at the standard C++ library, specifically the std::string type.

Comment: @Craig if we want a correct result, the calculated length simply *must not* be too short. If we're sure that it is so, we *can* use `strcat()`

Comment: @Craig yes I noticed it and I replaced it with `malloc` but still getting this errors: `In function ‘main’:
fun27.c:22:21: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
fun27.c:26:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:235:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
`

Comment: @user227666: You are calling `strchr(argv[i], " ");`.  This function takes a character, not a pointer to a string (character array).  Try `strchr(argv[i], ' ')` instead.

Comment: @Ingo: That's how all overflow vulnerabilities start out.  At some point, this code will be refactored/modified/hoisted somewhere else.  When that happens, you might not have the same guarantees.  It's referred to as secure coding best practices.

Comment: @Craig I know what you mean but the problem is that as soon as the size isn't calculated correctly any more, the result will be wrong anyway

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer.  I made a comment there too.  You just have to run the program with 20 arguments and you will get a buffer overflow.  It doesn't take into account the number of spaces being appended and no safety checks are performed using strncat.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Of course you are right. My first approaches only should give a hint how it could be implemented. But for sake of completeness I changed my post. And there more things to keep an eye on like escaping existing " characters, testing if malloc was successful etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.

In Windows, you can use [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).